# How would you represent "easy"?

Tags: buttons, icons

I'm working on an app that requires someone to rate the how they did at recalling an item (to which they are shown the correct answer before they rate the item).  The three options are: wrong, right, and easy.  With easy meaning that it was right they didn't have to think about it to get the answer.

I'm open to suggestions of name changes that improve the clarity, but this question is more about how to make it easier for users to scan them without having to read the text each time - with particular interest on the "easy" option.

Two example mockups we have so far are:

[image]

and

[image]

How would you represent these 3 buttons, and what improvements can you suggest over the current ones, with emphasis on the easy option?

Comment: Will the user know whether they have done a task wrong? Could be an idea to simplify it to just 'difficult' or 'easy'.

Comment: Yes, I should probably reword the question.  They are trying to recall something and when they see the answer they rate how they did at recalling the item.

Comment: It would be slightly painful for the people who now have to answer both "Wrong" _and_ "Easy" ;)

Comment: I agree - decide first on what you are trying to measure, and that may drive the UI.  Right vs. Wrong is just common sense, but "easy" just doesn't fit that pattern.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

PhilipW is right in that you don't need to say *right*, because that implies that *easy* might not also be *right*. I'm assuming a task has to be completed to get to this stage and that users have some indication of right and wrong, and that they have some element of measurement by which they can consider the task to be easy or hard?

Based on the information given, here's a visual that might be easier to scan:

[image]

[edit1] added comparison following Gilbert's comment

[image]

[edit2] and here's a couple of options that group the hard and easy as both *not being wrong* (ie right!)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Love the double tick for easy.

Comment: Nice visual buttons.  I'm concerned that making the Easy button green sends a subliminal message to the user that the tasks are supposed to be easy.  Maybe yellow would be better?

Comment: good point (and assuming they *aren't* all supposed to be easy.) @JohnGB - what is the outcome (and for whom) when the user clicks more on hard than easy.

Comment: @Roger Attrill: Can you think of a way of showing that both Hard and Easy are grouped and both represent correct?  My worry is that people will think of "hard" as incorrect.

Comment: @JohnGB Make both hard and easy the same color/same hue at least? Or put the buttons so that Hard and Easy are nearer to each other than to Wrong (Look up Gestalt Laws for more ideas :)

Comment: edit made - I nearly did this in the first place actually!

Comment: It's answers like this that make me love coming here...

Comment: @RogerAttrill: Me likes :)

Comment: I'm not sure I'd ever tick "hard" if I got the right answer, unless it took 15 minutes and required me to phone a friend and plow through 3 volumes of ancient scrolls first... if I found the answer after some normal thinking I'd feel inclined to tick "easy" - perhaps the wording for "hard" and "easy" could be adjusted to reflect that "hard" is simply "not zero effort".

Comment: I think one of the first two options gets the idea across best - and gives the idea of a 0 / 5 / 10 score kind of scale - without any other complication.

Answer (score 4):

I'd go for a 3 button scale - arranged in order:

Wrong / Difficult / Easy.

You don't need to say right - as this is implied by the first option 'wrong'.

Comment: Good point.  That does indeed help clarify the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Wrong, Right, Too easy

The too easy should maybe have the same visual clues as the Right option.
Too easy is still Right, right?

Comment: +1 I disagree with the "difficult" or "hard" button labels as even if something wasn't easy/obvious - I think someone judging their own effort won't tick "difficult" or "hard" even if they had to think for a while...

Answer (score 2):

I'd make the three options refer specifically to difficulty - "Couldn't do it!", "Difficult!", "Easy!". This makes more sense to the user (there's three comparable options), but because your options now easily fit a 'sliding scale', you can use imagery based on traffic-light schemes or numbers.

For instance, you could now use a set of coloured faces (red / angry - impossible, yellow / neutral - tricky, green / happy - simple) or sets of one, two and three domain-relevant icons, with the number signifying difficulty (eg, for recipes, one chef's hat for easy, two for tricky, and three for impossible).

Comment: How do you fit "couldn't do it!" on a button?

Comment: Impossible? •••

Comment: <sub>couldn't do it</sub> - damn - that doesn't work in comments :-)

Comment: Larger buttons, shorter synonymns. There's a couple of things you could do. What's important is that the three options are directly comparable (e.g on a sliding scale), both for user perception (makes more sense to the reader) and because it provides more opportunities for iconography.